# How to add textbox search event. Items or listbox is in another wpf page

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make searchbox like when I search Items then listbox is show in this page. I have make listbox page is in another wpf window. Can you please help on this I am facing maki problem regarding this.

When I  search listbox Items from MainWindow.Xaml and click button then  of item show in main page. and Items on See software page.

Thankyou!

```
MainWindow.xaml


<Window Title="Welcome"  Background="#FFD6D6D6" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown"
AllowsTransparency="True" Height="600" Width="1050">
 <!--Make serchbar -->
                <Grid Background="#2892b5" Grid.Column="3" Margin="10,0,0,0" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="65">
                        <Image  Source="/Resources/search_32px.png" Height="40" Width="70" />
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="70,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                        <Label Content="Search for software" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"  Grid.Row="0"  Width="286"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <TextBox Background="White" Foreground="Black" x:Name="search" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" Margin="37,0,36,38"/>
                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Height="37" Width="37" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Image Source="/View/icons8_right_50px_1.png"/>
                    </Button>

                </Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    private void SearchClick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 

    }
```

**SeeSoftware.xaml**

```
<Window Title="SeeSoftware" Height="700" Width="800" WindowStyle="None"  MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">

<ListBox x:Name="Listbox" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" BorderBrush="Transparent"  Background="Transparent">
                                <ListBoxItem Height="50">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                        <Image Height="30" Width="30" Source="/Resources/vscode.jpeg"/>
                                        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" Margin="20,0,0,0" Content="Visual Studio code" />
                                        <TextBlock Margin="18,0,0,0" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                  <Hyperlink Foreground="White" NavigateUri="https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b/VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.73.1.exe" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                                  Install
                                      <Image Height="13" Source="/Resources/icons8_download_26px.png"/>
                                  </Hyperlink>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Please explain your problem better, and if you can also write down your code

Comment: when i click search button then whole listbox is show in testblock if i have added images label textbox every thing is showing